# replace characters in input form, but preserve the cursor position

Tags: jquery, input

I need to create a date entry form, something like:

```
<input type="text" id="field" maxlength="10" value="__/__/____"/>
```

and when the users enters the date value it should replace every bottom line with the value entered:

```
var firstValue= $("#field").val();

$("#field").keypress(function (e) {
  var pattern = /^\d*(\d*)?$/;
  var digit= String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if (digit.match(pattern)) {
    $("#field").val($("#field").val().replace("_", digit))
  }
  else 
    event.target.value = firstValue;
});
```

And everything works fine, except the cursor stays fixed at the end of the input form all the time during the input. Does someone know why is this happening and can you help me to get the cursor follow the input as it happens?

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-invent the wheel. Use the [**jQuery Masked Input Plugin**](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) instead:

> It allows a user to more easily enter fixed width input where you would like them to enter the data in a certain format (dates, phone numbers, etc). It has been tested on Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari and Chrome.